# Transition: rotate not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit

I have a loading page while the website is loading. It works fine in Chrome but I need to fix it on Safari because it's not working. Here's my code:

```css
.se-pre-con {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.loading {
  top: 30%;
  right: 45%;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-animation: spinHorizontal 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spinHorizontal 4s linear infinite;
  animation: spinHorizontal 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spinHorizontal {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="se-pre-con">
  <div class="loading">

    <img src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/4/Circle-PNG-Picture-279x279.png">
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML too?

Comment: done @BrettDeWoody

Comment: not necessarily the solution, but your image tag needs to close to be valid html like so: <img src="img.png" />

Answer (score 0):

It appears it has to do with the `position: fixed` on the `.se-pre-con` element. Try using `absolute` positioning or positioning it in another way.

```css
.se-pre-con {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.loading {
  width: 279px;
  height: 279px;
  top: 30%;
  right: 45%;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: spinHorizontal 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spinHorizontal 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spinHorizontal 2s linear infinite;
  background-color: transparent;
}

@keyframes spinHorizontal {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="se-pre-con">
  <div class="loading">

    <img src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/4/Circle-PNG-Picture-279x279.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works but i need a white background before the website loads, so now its showing the website content while loading @Brett DeWoody

Comment: Ok. I found another issue that might be causing it - the `position: fixed`.